# Equality of expressions containing complex numbers

Tags: complex, core-language, expression-test

I am using *Mathematica* to test the equivalence of symbolic expressions.  I run into what appears to be a bug when I test the equivalence of expressions involving an imaginary number taken to a complex power.  When I test the equivalence of such expressions that are clearly equal, mathematica does not recognize their equivalence.  Here is an example:

```
Assuming[k > 0 && m > 0, 
  {TrueQ[(2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I) (2 I k)^(I*m) == (2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I + I*m)]}]
```

> False

Interestingly, when I repeat the above test, except changing the `2 I k` to `I k`, *Mathematica* recognizes the equivalence:

```
Assuming[k > 0 && m > 0, 
  {TrueQ[(I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I)* (I k)^(I m) == (I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I + I*m)]}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Another interesting example I encountered was when taking an imaginary number to the power `Pi` vs. `N[Pi]`:

```
Assuming[k > 0 && m > 0, {TrueQ[(I k)^(Pi) (I k)^(I m) == (I k)^(Pi + I m)]}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Assuming[k > 0 && m > 0, {TrueQ[(I k)^(N[Pi]) (I k)^(I m) == (I k)^(N[Pi] + I m)]}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

I suspect these to be a bug in *Mathematica*.  Has anyone encountered similar problems with equivalence tests in *Mathematica*, or does anyone have an idea of what might be the cause if this apparent problem?

Comment: You will want to avoid inexact numbers in this application. Try replacing `0.1` with `1/10` in your first example, for instance.

Comment: Please, try to format your questions properly. If you visit the help centre you can read more about it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug.  It's a misunderstanding about what `TrueQ` does.

From the documentation,

> `TrueQ` will return `True` only if the input is explicitly `True`

To put it more explicitly, it's equivalent to `trueQ[expr_] := If[expr === True, True, False]`.

The expression `(2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I) (2 I k)^(I*m) == (2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I + I*m)` is not the symbol `True` (regardless of the fact whether it's mathematically true or not), so `TrueQ` returns `False.`

`(I k)^(Pi) (I k)^(I m) == (I k)^(Pi + I m)` evaluates to `True` immediately due to canonicalization of the power expression, so `TrueQ` returns `True`.

*`TrueQ` does not deal with symbolic mathematics at all.*  It simply checks if an expression is `True`, literally, or something else.  It does not even care about the meaning of the symbol `True`.

---

The correct way to handle this problem is to use `Simplify` instead of `TrueQ` and to only use [exact numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html).   `0.1` is not exact.

Comment: `Assuming[k > 0 && m > 0,  Simplify[(2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I) (2 I k)^(I*m) == (2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I + I*m)]]` ( i.e., with inexact numbers) evaluates to `True` on my system (Mma v10.1 with Mac OS 10.10.4). Although I agree that generally it is `best` when checking for equality to use exact numbers to avoid `potential` problems.

Answer (score 1):

What you are encountering is something all *Mathematica* users encounter because it is the way *Mathematica* works. Szabolcs has explained this well. However, I would like to add that you can fix the "problem" by using `Simplify`

```
Simplify[(2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I) (2*I*k)^(I*m) == (2*I*k)^(1 + 0.1*I + I*m)]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Simplify[(I k)^(N[Pi]) (I k)^(I m) == (I k)^(N[Pi] + I m)]
```

> ```
> True
> ```